# SQLite Sorting output using reference between two tables

Tags: database, sqlite, sorting

I have 3 tables (picture included) and I need to output data from table "Deals" sorted by date using price_date from table "Pricedates" which has the following format **yyyy-mm-dd**.

I have tried using

```
select euro_amount,id_price,id_deal 
from deals 
where id_client=9 
order by pricedates(price_date) DECSC 
Limit 1
```

but it didn't work.
Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must join the tables:

```
select 
  d.euro_amount,
  d.id_price,
  d.id_deal 
from deals d 
inner join prices p on p.id_price = d.id_price
inner join pricedates pd on pd.id_date = p.id_price_date
where d.id_client = 9 
order by pd.price_date desc 
limit 1
```

Comment: Hm, I keep getting an error: no such column: p.id_date.
Any ideas what may be wrong?

Comment: Working, but it gives me only one output, even though I have two id_client equal to 9...

Comment: Why did you put LIMIT 1? I kept it in my code. Remove it to get all the rows.